# Binary game that shows either 1 or 2, and counting the sequencing of 122 that occurs in 5 plays

Tags: combinatorics

so to check my approach, I missed this on the homework.  here is the problem, Say we have a machine that prints out either a "1" or "2" with equal probability for a single given play.   We play this game 5 times, and a sequence of 5 numbers prints out.  What is the expected number of sequences that includes "122" in 5 plays?

If we were to use an indicator function Let $I_j $= 1 if "122" occurs in 3 turns, 0 other wise.
E($I_j$)= $P(122$) = 1/8.
The challenge is we are asked for 5 flips, not 3.

In 5 plays we can have  "122"XX, X"122"X, or XX"122".  each of these X represent an 'open spot' that can print anything.

so each of these 3 events contain "122"  yielding 3/8 as the answer for part 1.

The second part of the question asks for the expected number of "122" sequence which appears in 10 plays of the game.

Isn't that $2* \frac{3*4}{2^5} = \frac{6}{8}= 0.75$ ?

Comment: Your answer to part $1$ seems right, but how did you get $2\cdot \frac{3\cdot 4}{2^5}$ for part $2$?